# Why does Maven use the wrong plugin despite explicit plugin and pluginManagement version?

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, versioning, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

My parent POM **explicitly** declares a [dependency on `maven-javadoc-plugin 2.9.1` (MJP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340970/maven-plugin-version-in-pom-seemingly-ignored) in both

```xml
    <pluginManagement>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
         </plugin>
            ...
        <reporting>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.9.1</version>
             ...
```

and `mvn help:effective-pom` shows 2.9.1 is being used. However, the build is using 2.10 which is causes build failures. This is like
[maven-javadoc-plugin breaks mvn release:perform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983852/maven-javadoc-plugin-breaks-mvn-releaseperform).
`mvn help:describe -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins -DartifactId=maven-javadoc-plugin`
shows

```bash
Name: Apache Maven Javadoc Plugin
Description: The Apache Maven Javadoc Plugin is a plugin that uses the javadoc tool for generating javadocs for the specified project.
Group Id: org.apache.maven.plugins
Artifact Id: maven-javadoc-plugin
Version: 2.10
Goal Prefix: javadoc
```

Meanwhile, `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` shows
`[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-javadoc-plugin-2.9.1.jar`.
Yet when I run the build, mvn uses MJP version 2.10 instead, causing a build failure. I'm using Maven version 3.2.1.

How can I force maven to use 2.9.1 and not the broken 2.10?

Comment: Have you checked the full dependency tree, to see if some other dependency is also importing the javadoc plugin?

Comment: How do I do that? I ran mvn dependency:resolve-plugins and it reports 2.9.1

Comment: I "fixed" the problem by deleting my ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin. I'm not writing this as an answer to the question; I would still like to see better Maven dependency: tools to show the dependency chains (i.e. what plugin 'forced' the use of 2.10 contrary to the pom.xml). Hopefully the steps I took to diagnose and the workaround will help others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure that you are looking at the right dependency.  We are seeing that 2.9.1 as specified is being used for site reports but 2.10 is being used by the build.  I believe you should specify it in your

> `<build><plugins>`

section as well.

We just verified that we were suffering the same problem.  We had the plugin version in the reporting plugins section but not build plugins.  Once we added it to the build plugins section, the issue was resolved.  The reason it needed to be in build plugins was because it was being used in the prepare deploy phase to build a javadoc jar.  This happens separately from generating javadoc for the site reports.

Comment: I've tried that, too, and mvn help:describe still shows Version: 2.10 -- strange! But as with adding it to pluginManagement, the build succeeds and -X shows maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:javadoc (once my repo was cleaned out). I think all together, this is enough of an answer