# Mismatch of surefire version in console and pom file

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I have added plugin for maven-surefire-plugin version -2.22.0 in pom.xml file but when i run build then its displaying as different version in console as maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4. I have cleaned the project multiple times and build but still seeing same issue.
In Pom :-

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <configuration>
           <includes>
                <include>**/*CucumberRunnerTest.java</include>
                </includes>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

In console :-
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Also , i thing i noticed under Effective Pom file beside POM tab , Version is 2.12.4
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340970/maven-plugin-version-in-pom-seemingly-ignored